# Is there any option to repeat the background?

Tags: windows-phone-7, repeater, background-image, windows-phone

I am using a horizontal long bar in my application.

The size of screen varies upon the devices, so maintaining a size in resources is not a good practice.

Is it possible to repeat the image in horizontal axis in wp7.

Comment: yes it is image. i am trying to repeat a 5pix image in horizontal axis.

Comment: Currently Windows Phone 7 only supports 480 x 800 screen resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no repeat behavior in Silverlight's XAML (unlike WPF which supports it).

It is not recommanded to follow this way on the phone. You should create a larger image which includes the tiled effect at design time. You app will run faster because it will reduce the amount of work your app needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Windows Phone 7 only supports 480 x 800 screen resolutions, although this will change in Windows Phone 8. Why not just resize the background? If you really want, you could create a repeating background image in an image editor, set it as the background image, and set stretch to none.

Comment: If you make a WP8 version of your app, you will need to worry about different resolutions again.